# Highcharts combination plots with animation in R

Tags: r, animation, plot, highcharts, combinations

I try to create a bar chart with dot together and animate along time say different weeks. I can create them separately with animation. But cannot put them (overlay together). Here is the dataset and how it looks like separate. Is any suggestion how to make dot and bar together?

Thank you very much!

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
weeks <- 96
nx <- 3
ny <- 20
df<-data.frame(rep(seq(24,weeks,24), each = nx * ny), xVar = rep(1:nx, times = weeks/24* ny),zVar=rep(runif(20,min=c(0), max=c(1)),times=4*3),
               w1=rep(seq(1,4,1), each = nx * ny))
colnames(df)<-c('weeks','treatment', 'val','w1')
df<-df[order(df$weeks,df$treatment, df$val),]
df$valF<-NULL
df$valF<-df$val*df$w1*df$treatment*-1
df$valF[1:5]<-df$valF[1:5]*-1
df<-df[order(df$weeks,df$treatment, -df$valF),]
yVar<-rep(1:ny,times=weeks/24*nx)
yVar
df<-cbind(df,yVar)
df$yVar<-as.factor(df$yVar)
library(reshape2)
library(highcharter)
df$valF<-round(df$valF,2)
wide<-dcast(df, treatment+yVar~weeks, value.var="valF" )
colnames(wide)<-c('treatment', 'yVar','w24', 'w48','w72','w96')

for (i in 1:60){wide$value[i]=list(list(sequence = c(wide$w24[i],wide$w48[i],wide$w72[i],wide$w96[i]
)))}

for (i in 1:60){wide$value2[i]=list(list(sequence = c(wide$w24[i]-1,wide$w48[i]-1,wide$w72[i]-1,wide$w96[i]-1
)))}

highchart() %>%
  hc_yAxis(max =1, min = -12)%>%
  #hc_xAxis(categories = categories_grouped) %>% 
   hc_add_series(data = wide$value[1:60], type = "column",  showInLegend = FALSE, color="skyblue")%>%
      hc_motion(enabled = TRUE,
            labels = c("week24", "week48","week72","week96"),
            series = c(0))

highchart() %>%
   hc_yAxis(max =1, min = -12)%>%
    hc_add_series(data = wide$value2[1:60], type = "scatter",name="n1",  showInLegend = FALSE, color="black")%>%
      hc_motion(enabled = TRUE,
            labels = c("week24", "week48","week72","week96"),
            series = c(0))


highchart() %>%
   hc_yAxis(max =1, min = -12)%>%
    hc_add_series(data = wide$value2[1:60], type = "scatter",name="n1",  showInLegend = FALSE, color="black")%>%
     hc_add_series(data = wide$value[1:60], type = "column", name="n2",  showInLegend = FALSE, color="skyblue")%>%
      hc_motion(enabled = TRUE,
            labels = c("week24", "week48","week72","week96"),
            series = c(0))
```

[data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAR2S.png)

[Barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M98OF.png)

[dotplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jQWs.png)

Comment: Try `series = c(0, 1)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! it works!